# BackboneJs - Retain events on a collection inside a model when model changes

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

i've a Collection inside a Model as illustrated below:

```
var itemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

   defaults:{
      name:"",
      brand:"",
      priceCollection:[]
    }
})
```

There are change listeners attached to the `itemModel` and  also change listeners attached to collection as 
 `this.listenTo(itemModel.get('priceCollection'),'change',this.dosomething)` in a view.

The problem is  that the change listeners on the collection work fine **as long as the parent model hasn't changed** , if the model is given a set of new attributes via `itemModel.set(newattributes)` the event bound on itemModel.get('priceCollection') is lost.

How do i retain this event? or should i rebind this event everytime the Model is change?  or Should i move the listener on the collection from the view to the Model and trigger a custom Backbone event?

It should be noted that this model is singleton

Comment: does new attributes contain property `priceCollection`..?

Comment: What you have in defaults is a simple array. When are you assigning it to a collection instance..? And how are you creating the new instance of collection before setting..? Ideally you should try to reuse the existing collection...

Comment: @TJ .. have shown it as an array for illustration purposes, but it is a proper collection of Backbone Model instances

Comment: You should share the actual code that is required to reproduce the problem see [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that Backbone assumes a Collection and Model should be mapped 1:1 to a server side resource. It makes clear assumtions on the API layout and data structures - refer to [`Model.url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url), [`Model.urlRoot`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) and [`Collection.url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url).

### Proposal

You said the model is a singleton. In this case I'd suggest to maintain the model and collection separately.

Since a `SomeModel` is not accompanied by a certain collection `SomeCollection` which have a tight relationship it's not necessary to relate them on an attribute level. The effort needed to establish event listeners and sync the data is only at one place.

```
// some controller (app main)

var model = new SomeSingletonModel();
var collection = new SomeSingletonCollection();

var view = new SomeView({
  model: model,
  collection: collection
});
```

Probably the resource that is mapped to `SomeSingletonModel` will deliver an array.

What are the benefits of using a collection as model attribute (that's what `model.get("name")` is) over using a plain array? Syncing and change events. Both are probably only necessary when a View updates the Collection's Models. When the View only renders, a Collection does not provide any benefit in many cases.

If the data of that array needs to be updated, using a Collection is probably the right choice because of Backbone's synching mechanisms.

But how to keep the collection sync with the model (you ask)?

Your controller needs to listen to the model and update the collection on `sync` and `reset`:

```
model.on("sync reset", function() {
  // "priceCollection" is a model attribute 
  collection.reset(model.get("priceCollection"));

  // optionally unset "priceCollection" on the model
  this.unset("priceCollection", { silent: true });
});
```

This will initialize the collection.

Any change to the Collection's Models will then only be part of the Collection's or Model's syncing mechanisms.

Comment: Well , came across this after sometime. But it was quite helpful. Thanks :) !

Answer (score 1):

### Foreword

Also see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36139197/1078886) which is probably the better choice when the model is a singleton.

Note the very first statement on Backbone's assumptions on the API design on that answer.

### Proposals using a coupling between Model and Collection

Note: if necessary, in all these implementations the Collection's `url` or Model's (the Collection's Model) `url`/`rootUrl` may get (re-)defined upon `sync` to control the syncing.

#### Update internal reference on change/sync/reset

This implementation removes the model attribute and updates an object attribute with its data.

The object attribute is one Collection instance that is only reset, not recreated, upon model change.

```
var CustomModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    // defaults go here - "children" may be contained here
  },

  // implement constructor to act before the parent constructor is able to
  // call set() (L402 in v1.3.0) with the initial values
  // See https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.3.0/backbone.js#L402
  constructor: function() {
    // create children collection as object attribute - replaces model attr.
    this.children = new Backbone.Collection();
    // listen to changing events to catch away that attribute an update the
    // object attribute
    this.listenTo(this, "change:children sync reset", this.onChangeColl);

    // apply original constructor
    Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  onChangeColl: function() {
    // check for presence since syncing will trigger "set" and then "sync",
    // the latter would then empty the collection again after it has been updated
    if (this.has("children")) {
      // update "children" on syncing/resetting - this will trigger "reset"
      this.children.reset(this.get("children"));

      // remove implicitly created model attribute
      // use silent to prevent endless loop due to change upon change event
      this.unset("children", { silent: true });
    }
  }
});
```

Example usage when testing in a Fiddle or console:

```
var c = new CustomModel({ a: 1, children: [{ x: 1 }, { x: 5 }] });
c.set({a: 8, children: [{ x: 50 }, { x: 89 }]});
c.url = "/dummy"
// replace sync() only for fetch() demo - the implementation does what sync() would do on success
c.sync = function(method, coll, opts){  if (method == "read") { opts.success({ a: 100, children: [{ x: 42 }, { x: 47 }] }); } }
c.fetch();
```

Pro

- listening to collection events is easier to implement since there's one instance through model lifetime

Contra

- code is more complex
- collection data is not part syncing without further implementations

---

#### Replace on change/sync/reset

This implementation intercepts model attribute changes and replaces its data with a Collection instance that has been initialized (reset) with the raw data.

```
var CustomModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    // this is optional
    children: new Backbone.Collection()
  },

  initialize: function() {
    // listen to model attribute changing events to swap the raw data with a
    // collection instance
    this.listenTo(this, "change:children sync reset", this.onChangeColl);
  },

  onChangeColl: function() {
    if (this.has("children")) {
      // use silent to prevent endless loop due to change upon change event
      this.set("children", new Backbone.Collection(this.get("children")), { silent: true });
    }
  }
});
```

Example usage when testing in a Fiddle or console:

```
var c = new CustomModel({ a: 1, children: [{ x: 1 }, { x: 5 }] });
c.set({ a: 8, children: [{ x: 50 }, { x: 89 }] });
c.url = "/dummy";
// replace sync() only for fetch() demo - the implementation does what sync() would do on success
c.sync = function(method, coll, opts){  if (method == "read") { opts.success({ a: 100, children: [{ x: 42 }, { x: 47 }] }); } }
c.fetch();
```

Pro

- straightforward implementation

Contra

- data included in sync, excluding it takes more effort
- listening to the Collection impractical: since all consumers would need to unbind/bind

Note: depending on your requirements and API design you may not want `children` being synced to the server automatically. In this case this solution is limited. You could overwrite `toJSON()` of the Model but this may limit its usage for other parts of the application (like feeding the data into a view).

---

#### Inverse relation: Collection has a Model

Maybe your primary data is actually the Collection. So decorating a Collection with additional data is another approach. This implementation provides one model along the Collection that will be updated upon collection sync.

This implementation is only best suited for fetch of collection data along with attributes (e.g. fetching directory contents with attributes of the directory itself).

```
var CustomCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   initialize: function() {
      // maintain decorative attributes of this collection
      this.attrs = new Backbone.Model();
   },

   parse: function(data, opts) {
      // remove "children" before setting the remainder to the Model
      this.attrs.set(_.omit(data, "children"));
      // return the collection content only
      return data.children;
   }
});
```

Example usage when testing in a Fiddle or console:

```
var c = new CustomCollection({ a: 1, b: 2, children: [{ x: 2 }, { x: 3 }] }, { parse: true });
c.reset({ a: 9, b: 11, children: [{ x: 5 }, { x: 10 }] } , { parse: true });
// replace sync() only for fetch() demo - the implementation does what sync() would do on success
c.sync = function(method, coll, opts){ if (method == "read") { opts.success({ a: 100, b: 124, children: [{ x: 42 }, { x: 47 }] }) } }
c.fetch();
```

Pro

- straight forward implementation
- delegating model events is easier

Contra

- collection data is not part syncing without further implementations
- requires `parse()` to be implemented which
  -- in turn requires `parse: true` to always be passed to `reset()` and `set()` and
  -- requires `parse()` to be called with the collection as scope (`this`) (this could be circumvented by defining `parse` within `initialize` bound to `this` using `bind()´)